# role of esb in http rest services?

Tags: java, api, rest, esb

I have large number of http REST based API implemented in java being reused by multiple services and web/mobile clients.

I have been told that services are connecting based on point to point integration, in other words, if an orchestration service A wants to use rest based service B and C, it uses their load balanced IP. I can esily add more service instances behind the load balancer. So, what would i gain by using ESB?

Answer (score 0):

ESB is more intelligent than a load balancer. Many ESBs offer load balancer capabilites too.

ESB comes into play when you want to connect to services that adhere to different message formats. Say, you have a service that is REST based and can process http payload. But you have a client that sends only jms messages with that payload. An ESB can handle this case. It acts as an integrator accepting the jms messages and converts it to payload.

You might want an ESB even if you are connecting to services talking the same message format. ESB can inspect and transform the message too.